# Nginx Primary script unknown (fastcgi_param + alias)

Tags: nginx, php, fastcgi

I'm using Laravel in a serverblock and I'd like to create an alias, for example /webmail. This results in an nginx "`Primary script unknown`" error. I think I need to change my `fastcgi_param`. Can anyone help me?

Below is the important part about my Nginx serverblock.

```
server {

    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    set $root_path '/var/www/html/public';
    root $root_path;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /webmail {
        root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

So my webmail application is located in `/var/www/webmail`.

Webmail works when I change the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
```

However, the root domain doesn't work anymore after this change. I can't place the line above in the location section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
server {

    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    set $root_path '/var/www/html/public';
    root $root_path;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_path$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   $root_path;
    }

    location /webmail {
        set $root_path '/var/www';
        root $root_path;
    }
}
```

So, we pass a different document root / script filename prefix to PHP depending on the location. On default locations we have `$root_path` set to `/var/www/html/public` and on `/webmail` we set it to `/var/www`.

You may need to add a separate `rewrite` / `try_files` section in the `/webmail` location, so that `index.php` or any other default webmail entry script is tried. You need to look at your webmail's documentation for this.

Comment: I'm currently testing it with Laravel in my subdirectory, but this still returns the same message. Any suggestions?`